# ios - nsoperationqueue - downloading images from server

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I want to use NSOperationQueue in my app and start downloading the images from server.
If my app goes to background or be terminated, will NSOperationQueue still continues downloading them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `NSOperationQueue` will not continue working when the app is moved to the background. You would need to explicitly action this by using the method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

This is covered in [Technical Note TN2277 - Networking and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2277/_index.html)

See also [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), specifically the section on App States and Multitasking.

As an aside, could I recommend that you instead use the [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) library. It handles a lot of this functionality for you. Specifically, each class is a subclass of `NSOperation`.

Moreover, it already has an image downloader class in [AFImageRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFImageRequestOperation.h). So that should be very useful for you. `AFImageRequestOperation` is a subclass of [AFURLConnectionOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h) so you have access to the method `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

Of course, all this relates to multitasking so it is only available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Comment: Using ASIHttp also its possible, but I would like to know how they are implementing background downloads.

Comment: I would avoid Asihttp as it is no longer supported. AFNetworking is your best option.

Comment: what ever it is, either ASIHttp or AFNetworking, how is be being developed? What classes/frameworks are they using and achieving it?

Comment: you can download it using the link above from GitHub. Have a look at the source code.